# Unrecognised header byte error when try to decode an Avro message in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to write a test case for my Spring Cloud Stream application. I am using **Confluent Schema Registry** with **Avro**, so I need to decode the message after polling from the channel. Here is my code:

```
    processor.input()
        .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(InputData).build());

    Message<?> message = messageCollector.forChannel(processor.output()).poll();

    BinaryMessageDecoder<OutputData> decoder = OutputData.getDecoder();
    OutputData outputObject = decoder.decode((byte[]) message.getPayload());
```

For some reason this code throws

> org.apache.avro.message.BadHeaderException: Unrecognized header bytes: 0x00 0x08

I am not sure if this is some sort of bug I am facing or I am not following a proper way to decode the received avro message. I suspect I need to set header with something, but I am not quite sure how and with what exactly. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this matter.

P.S: I am using `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` for the purpose of this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was related to how I was trying to decode the Avro message. By using the official Avro libraries, the following code worked for me:

```
Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder((byte[]) message.getPayload(), null);
DatumReader<OutputData> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(OutputData.getClassSchema());

RawDataCapsule rawDataCapsule = reader.read(null , decoder);
```

Answer (score 1):

The data won't be avro-encoded when using the test binder.

The test binder is very limited.

To properly test end-to-end with avro, you should remove the test binder and use the real kafka binder with an embedded kafka broker.

One of the [sample apps](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/testing-samples/test-embedded-kafka) shows how to do it.

Comment: When I took a look at the byte array it looks to be legit Avro message. However, the auto-generated byte decoder is not able to decode it. I suspect it cannot even be used for this matter. So I tried it with the official Avro decoder (i.e. DatumReader and DecoderFactory) and it works. Do you know why it was not working with the approach that is raised in the question?